# Avoid "Using temporary" and "Using filesort" with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization

sorry but after browsing nearly every posts and questions about it, I still can't manage to get rid of "Using temporary" and "Using filesort" in a simple query. I know this is a problem of keys but I can't find the right combination...

I also don't know if the order of the join defined by the optimizer is ok, I tested other orders using STRAIGHT_JOIN but nothing better... The query is pretty slow using ORDER BY, but really fast without it and of course without "Using temporary" and "Using filesort"! (there is something like 100.000 rows in points table)

The query :

```
SELECT points.id,
points.id_owner,
points.point_title,
points.point_desc,
users.user_id,
users.username
FROM points,
JOIN users ON points.id_owner = users.user_id
JOIN follows ON follows.id_followed = points.id_owner
WHERE points.deleted = 0
AND follows.id_follower = 22
ORDER BY points.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

the explain :

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | follows | ref    | FOLLOW_DUO    | FOLLOW_DUO | 4       | const               |    2 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users   | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | follows.id_followed |    1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | points  | ref    | GETPOINT1     | GETPOINT1  | 5       | users.user_id,const |  460 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

And here is the SHOW INDEX from the three tables :

```
SHOW INDEX FROM points
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| points |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | id              | A         |       91987 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| points |          0 | GETPOINT1    |            1 | id_owner        | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| points |          0 | GETPOINT1    |            2 | deleted         | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| points |          0 | GETPOINT1    |            3 | id              | A         |       91987 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

SHOW INDEX FROM users
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| users |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | user_id     | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

SHOW INDEX FROM follows
+---------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| follows |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| follows |          0 | FOLLOW_DUO  |            1 | id_follower | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| follows |          0 | FOLLOW_DUO  |            2 | id_followed | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| follows |          1 | id_follower |            1 | id_follower | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| follows |          1 | id_followed |            1 | id_followed | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

From now I don't know what to test to try to avoid the "Using temporary" and "Using filesort"... So if you have an idea for me... Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Have you read the MySQL docs on [optimizing LIMIT queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html) and [optimizing ORDER BY queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html)?

Comment: @Catcall yes I have, but if I understand the problem, I can't figure how to avoid it in this case... :(

Comment: How did you *try* to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like so many rows are being examined from points table. I had tried following trick to avoid temporary table usage in my project. Please do as follows and give it an explain to see any improvement:

1. Delete all indexes called `'GETPOINT1'` except Primary Key Index form points table.
2. Add covering index on columns `(deleted, id_owner)`. Please keep the order of columns as mentioned.
3. If you still don't see any improvement, remove above index and add index again in order `(id, deleted, id_owner)` and `(deleted, id_owner, id)` columns and try again
4. In addition you may remove `follows.id_follower = 22` from where clause and put it in join condition like `JOIN follows ON follows.id_followed = points.id_owner AND follows.id_follower = 22`
5. Please also add index in order as `(id_follower, id_owner)` in `follows` table.

I do not guarantee but above should be able to give you improvements.